# Why do we not include contributions from $\delta(x)$ in the energy eigenvalue of the delta potential bound state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

Consider a [delta function potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential) $V(x)=-\alpha \delta(x)$. There is a bound state

$$\psi(x) = \frac{\sqrt{m\alpha}}{\hbar} \exp\left(-\frac{m\alpha|x|}{\hbar^2}\right),$$
with energy eigenvalue
$$E=-\frac{m\alpha^2}{2\hbar^2}.$$

However, if we plug the wavefunction into
$$E=\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle,$$
then we get
$$E=\left\langle\psi\middle|\frac{p^2}{2m}\middle|\psi\right\rangle-\alpha\langle\psi|\delta(x)|\psi\rangle\\
= -\frac{m\alpha^2}{2\hbar} - \frac{m\alpha}{\hbar^2}\int \exp\left(-\frac{2m\alpha|x|}{\hbar^2}\right)\delta(x)\, dx\\
=-\frac{3m\alpha^2}{2\hbar^2},$$

which is not equal to the eigenvalue. So how do we get around not including the contribution from $\delta(x)$ in $\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: How is $\langle p^2/2m\rangle$ negative?

Comment: exactly. In the final formula, your first term should be positive, so in the end you get $-m\alpha^2/2\hbar^2$.

Comment: By my calculations, the first term is positive as already pointed out by previous comments. Remember that the second derivative of $|x|$ at the origin is proportional to $\delta(x)$ so you get an additional contribution from there.

Comment: To clarify, the integrals in the regions $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately give $- \frac{m \alpha^2}{4\hbar^2}$ each which is what probably gave you the $-\frac{m \alpha^2}{2\hbar^2}$ that you have. The additional contribution from the Dirac delta function at the origin is $\frac{m \alpha^2}{\hbar^2}$ for a total of $+\frac{m \alpha^2}{2\hbar^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $\left|x\right|$ is not $1$, as seems to be required for the calculation of your eigenvalue to be $-\frac{m\alpha^{2}}{2\hbar^{2}}$

Instead, the right derivative in the sense of distributions, is,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left|x\right|=\theta\left(x\right)-\theta\left(-x\right)
$$
with $\theta$ being Heaviside's step function. When differentiating again, you get,
$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left|x\right|=\delta\left(x\right)+\delta\left(-x\right)
$$
You should be alright if you redo the calculation with these prescriptions.